# Steiner construction

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the Steiner construction generalized to a higher dimensional space. I'm reading *Griffiths & Harris. Principles of algebraic geometry*, page 529. They propose the following generalization:

---

*If $V_1$, $V_2$ are two $(n-2)$-planes in $\mathbb{P}^n$, we may choose any parametrization of the two pencils of hyperplanes $\{H_1(\lambda)\}$ and $\{H_2(\lambda)\}$ through $V_1$ and $V_2$ respectively such that $H_1(\lambda)\not=H_2(\lambda)$ for all $\lambda$, and consider the locus
$$Q=\bigcup\limits_\lambda H_1(\lambda)\cap H_2(\lambda)$$
$Q$ is readily seen to be an irreducible, nondegenerate hypersurface, and hence a quadric, intersecting a general line $L\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ in the fixed points of the automorphism of $L$ sending $L\cap H_1(\lambda)$ to $L\cap H_2(\lambda)$. $Q$ is a quadric of rank either 3 or 4, with vertex $V_1\cap V_2$*

---

First of all, how do I prove that $Q$ is a quadric? Also, why is the rank 3 or 4 and why is $V_1\cap V_2$ the vertex? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: They tell you in what you typed how to see that it's a quadric: intersect with a general line. I'm not saying this is obvious, but if you can work out the details in that sentence you should find that the intersection is in 2 points. Do you understand the corresponding argument in the planar case a few paragraphs above?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I see know that the argument is exactly the same as in the planar case. Do you know something about the rank?

Comment: I don't know how to finish the argument, but notice that the (generalized) vertex of the quadric is $V_1 \cap V_2$, an $(n-3)$-plane. The fact that the vertex is so "large" should imply that it has low rank.